# Windows 10 weird screen glitch after sleep with Nvidia Game Ready driver 445.75

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card

These weird screen glitches are getting more and more common on my laptop after waking up and I am worry it could damage it. These glitches started to show up after updating Nvidia Game Ready driver to 445.75 (Half Life: Alyx update). How can I fix it?

[image: Weird screen glitch]

Also I don't know how the os managed to take the screenshot with the glitch on it.

Specs:

- OS: Windows 10 Home 10.0.18363 Build 18363
- Processor: Intel Core i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz, 2208 Mhz, 6 Cores 12 logical processors
- RAM: 16GB
- Laptop: Asus ROG Strix GL703GS_703GS
- Graphics Card: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070 (driver version: 26.24.14.4575)

Comment: Google says 445.75 is broken & needs to be updated.

Comment: A simple driver error that screws up the screen should not damage it, but update the Video driver and be sure to update BIOS and Chipset at the same time. Chipset can figure into video.

Comment: Roll back the driver in Device Manager

Comment: The rollback option is disabled, also Google didn't say that but Nvidia forums with no solutions at all

Comment: @Lolpez - The Nvidia website has every support driver for your card.  Download the previous version from there.